# creating a class for Radiobutton for python gui

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, inner-classes

Hello I am new to python and I have just completed basic python course and I right now I am working on python GUI using `tkinter`. I came across a task to create multiple `radiobuttons` and I was thinking to make a class for that to make it more simple both codes are given the working code is given below:

```
def radcall():
    radSel = radVar.get()
    if radSel ==1:
        win.configure(background=COLOR1)
    elif radSel == 2:
        win.configure(background=COLOR2)
    elif radSel == 3:
        win.configure(background=COLOR3)

#creating 3 radiobuttons
radVar=tk.IntVar()
rad1 = tk.Radiobutton(win, text =COLOR1, variable=radVar, value=1,
                        command=radcall)
rad1.grid(column=0,row=4)                       
rad2 = tk.Radiobutton(win, text = COLOR2, variable=radVar, value=2,
                        command=radcall)
rad2.grid(column=1,row=4)
rad3 = tk.Radiobutton(win, text = COLOR3, variable=radVar, value=3,
                        command=radcall)                        
rad3.grid(column=2,row=4)
```

the update I made in class is given below:

```
  class radbut():

    def __init__(self,win,text,variable,value,col,ro):
        self.win=win
        self.text=text
        self.variable=variable
        self.value=value
        self.col=col
        self.ro=ro

    def configure(self):
        if self.variable==1:
            print("in if statement")
            self.win.configure(background=COLOR1)
            return tk.Radiobutton(self.win,self.text,self.variable,self.value).grid(column = self.col,row = self.ro)
        elif self.variable == 2:
            self.win.configure(background=COLOR2)
            return tk.Radiobutton(self.win,self.text,self.variable,self.value).grid(column = self.col,row = self.ro)
        elif self.variable == 3:
            self.win.configure(background=COLOR3)
            return tk.Radiobutton(self.win,self.text,self.variable,self.value).grid(column = self.col,row = self.ro)
cast = radbut(win,COLOR1,'BLUE',1,0,4)
cast.configure()
```

Now when I run the code I don't get any error but I don't see any `radiobuttons` either so i want to know if it is even possible to create classes like this.. and if yes then how  what changes do I need to make

Answer (score 2):

You create the instance `cast` with the argument `variable = 'BLUE'`. Then you test the variable for values 1, 2 and 3. So none of the if statements evaluate to True.

In the if statements you set the window background color instead of creating a function to associate with selecting a button.

Then you return the created and gridded Radiobutton. But grid always returns None.

Here's an example where I'm treating the whole array of radiobuttons as one unit which can be gridded or packed together. All buttons have the same callback function, `change()` which reads the choice and sets the bg color accordingly.

```
from tkinter import *

win = Tk()
win.geometry('300x200+800+50')

colors = ['khaki', 'thistle', 'bisque']

class radbut(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, colors, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)
        self.master = master
        self.colors = colors

        self.choice = IntVar()
        self.choice.set(0)

        # Using a loop to create all alternatives in the list: colors
        for index, color in enumerate(colors):
            b = Radiobutton(self, text=color, variable=self.choice,
                            value=index, command=self.change)
            b.grid(row=0, column=index)

    def change(self):
        self.master.config(bg=self.colors[self.choice.get()])
        print('change')

cast = radbut(win, colors)
cast.grid(row=4, column=0)

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Sorry about that. I'm adding an example.

Comment: Your text says checkbutton but your code uses radiobutton

Comment: Must have been nodding off. Corrected now.